# WPF VB - TemplateBinding Fill on Custom User Control and XAML

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, dependency-properties, templatebinding

Making my first WPF application and I'm having problems with a custom user control that I have created. The custom control is a little football shirt made with paths and two labels, one for name and one for number. Eventually the user will adjust the formation of a team using this control, but the fill colour should match the team selected. I've set up a dependency property for the fill / brush which I hoped I could edit in my XAML, but the fill is transparent no matter what colour I set it too. What am I doing wrong? And is this the best way to make such a control that I can drag around a canvas / drop onto other panels to swap data. Here is the code:

PlayerIcon.xaml -

```
<UserControl x:Class="PlayerIcon"
         x:Name="PlayerIcon"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:RowZedPlus"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="60" d:DesignWidth="100">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="19"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White">
        <TextBlock Name="PlayerName" Foreground="White" FontSize="8">
            HELLO
        </TextBlock>
    </Label>

    <Canvas Margin="0,0,40,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- Jersey/Main Shirt -->
        <Path x:Name="PlayerShirt" Stroke="#ff000000" Fill="{TemplateBinding Custom:PlayerIcon.PlayerColour}" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Data="F1 M 0.899,9.143 C 0.899,9.143 3.484,14.188 3.984,17.000 C 6.484,15.562 9.984,15.562 9.984,15.562 L 9.984,37.625 C 9.984,37.625 25.297,40.438 31.672,37.625 C 31.609,29.250 31.672,15.562 31.672,15.562 C 31.672,15.562 35.922,15.812 37.234,16.812 C 37.234,16.812 37.554,12.941 40.421,9.253 L 24.386,3.357 C 23.526,6.286 20.586,8.812 20.586,8.812 C 20.586,8.812 18.047,6.857 16.922,3.500 C 16.922,3.500 2.790,8.143 0.899,9.143 Z">
        </Path>
        <!-- Jersey/Left Sleeve -->
        <Path StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#ff000000" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Fill="White" Data="F1 M 1.484,9.000 C 1.484,9.000 4.109,15.230 5.984,16.168 L 3.734,17.250 C 3.734,17.250 0.250,13.188 0.250,9.375 L 1.484,9.000 Z"/>
        <!-- Jersey/Right Sleeve -->
        <Path StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#ff000000" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Fill="White" Data="F1 M 39.688,9.000 C 39.688,9.000 37.062,15.230 35.188,16.168 L 37.438,17.250 C 37.438,17.250 40.922,13.188 40.922,9.375 L 39.688,9.000 Z"/>
        <!-- Jersey/Left Collar -->
        <Path StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#ff000000" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Fill="White" Data="F1 M 16.922,3.500 L 14.711,4.244 C 14.711,4.244 16.672,9.438 18.109,10.500 L 20.586,8.812 C 20.586,8.813 17.109,5.875 16.922,3.500 Z"/>
        <!-- Jersey/Right Collar -->
        <Path StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#ff000000" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Fill="White" Data="F1 M 24.386,3.357 L 26.504,4.136 C 26.504,4.136 24.636,9.294 23.198,10.357 L 20.734,8.750 C 20.734,8.750 24.198,5.732 24.386,3.357 Z"/>
        <!-- Jersey/Bottom Shirt -->
        <Path StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#ff000000" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Fill="White" Data="F1 M 9.984,36.875 C 17.172,38.688 25.609,38.812 31.734,36.875 L 31.734,37.938 C 25.922,40.312 18.160,40.312 9.984,37.938 C 9.984,37.938 9.984,37.188 9.984,36.875 Z"/>
        <!-- Jersey/<Path> -->
        <Path StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#fffb02ef" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Data="F1 M 7.422,45.375"/>

        <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#FFED0606">
            <TextBlock Name="PlayerNumber" Margin="5,5,0,0" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            </TextBlock>
        </Label>
    </Canvas>



</Grid>
```

PlayerIcon.xaml.vb -

```
Partial Public Class PlayerIcon

Public Shared ReadOnly PlayerColourProperty As DependencyProperty = _
                   DependencyProperty.Register("PlayerColour", _
                   GetType(Brush), GetType(PlayerIcon), _
                   New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red))

Public Property PlayerColour() As Brush
    Get
        Return GetValue(PlayerColourProperty)
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Brush)
        SetValue(PlayerColourProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

MainWindow.xaml -

```
<Custom:PlayerIcon PlayerColour="Green"></Custom:PlayerIcon>
<Custom:PlayerIcon Canvas.Left="300" PlayerColour="Purple"></Custom:PlayerIcon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using a `RelativeSource` binding for this.

As documentation for [TemplateBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) states you can only use it in `ControlTemplate` definitions.

Try switching `Fill="{TemplateBinding Custom:PlayerIcon.PlayerColour}"` to

```
Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                              AncestorType={x:Type Custom:PlayerIcon}},
                Path=PlayerColour}"
```

You are on the right path AFAIK w.r.t to this `UserControl`. You've got the control abstracted. You can now expand the functionality and tie them into their corresponding bits accordingly.

**on a side-note**:

Nice football jersey `Path` btw :) looks nice

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, i'll give this a try tomorrow morning and let you know how I get on. P.S. I used an Illustrator to XAML convertor for the jersey!

Comment: @RyanMcKenna your welcome :) You know you can just use Expression Blend to import Illustrator *.ai files into your project right? you don't need an external converter. Blend also retains all Artboards as Canvas items with Path children. That's what we do too ;)

Comment: That worked a treat! Hey, thanks for all your great tips. It's really appreciated.